# Any ideas on getting the count of users a record is shared to

Tags: apex, soql, lightning-web-components, sharing, public-group

I'm building a LWC that gives a metric for 'sentiment' but counting the occurrences of used topics in the host record pages feed.

It would be nice to be able to have a metric like "75% of Users with access to this record Posted #agreed"... but to do that I need to know how many people have access to the record.

Have started down the path of apex dynamic database query that gets the sObject name from the record page RecordId and converts it to sObject__Share then starts counting shares but amn't liking the need to do a recursive query through GroupMember when the record is shared to a group.

SO... Has anyone done anything similar or has any big brain ideas I'm missing?

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.